# Using the second moment to estimate parameter $p$ for a Geometric distribution, it is unbiased or not? If it is biased, how to compute it?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Using the second moment (method of moment) to estimate parameter $p$ for a Geometric distribution with $\mu=1/p$ and $var = 1/p^2$, it is unbiased or not? If it is biased, how to compute the bias?
Here is what I did.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd3Fm.png)

Comment: There is a direct relationship between the second moment and p.  The question makes sense only if the second moment is an estimate.  Then you need to know the statistics that led to the estimate of the second moment.

Comment: @herbsteinbergThanks for replying me. I have edited the question and specified something, would you like to like it again? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You approach seems to be correct.  In general, an unbiased estimate of the variance uses division by N-1 rather than division by N (sample size).  This approach applies to any distribution where the variance is finite. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation

Comment: @herbsteinbergThanks for helping me!